# Not able to handle security risk modal popuup box

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

After entering login credentials, I am getting this box. After clicking on `Yes` it is again redirected to `login page`. Again we need to provide username/password.Then it displays `HOME` page.

I tried with this code but did not work.

```
Alert simpleAlert = driver.switchTo().alert();
simpleAlert.accept();
```

Comment: Pop-up text "This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This poses a security risk. Do you want to continue?"  and provided buttons "Yes" and "No" . After pressing "Yes" it is redirected again to its login page. I want to click on "Yes" button and it is not working at my end ....

Comment: are you using mozilla?

Comment: No... I am using IE 8

Answer (score 0):

Disable internet explorer security pop -up :-

Refer below:-

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/05/14/mixed-content-and-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx